# Call JQuery Mobile transition with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, transition, swipe

I am using Hammer.js to add a swipe gesture to swipe through the pages of my website.

Now I want to add an transition using JQuery Mobile but the transition are called in HTML. Is there a possibility to call the animation:

```
data-transition="slide"
```

via Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hammertime = Hammer('html', {swipe_max_touches: 2, prevent_mouseevents: true
}).on("swiperight", function(event) {
document.location = "http://example.com";
});
```

Comment: I know the new function of JQuery Mobile "swipe to navigate" but I would like to use Hammer.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: "slideup" });
```

See [jQueryMobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

To improve the load times you can use [prefetching](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/) e.g.

```
<a href="url" data-prefetch="true" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-link">
  This link will prefetch the page
</a>
```

Comment: You can use prefetching to try and speed up the load times

Answer (score 3):

`$.mobile.changePage()` is deprecated now. http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/. The proper way would be to use:

1. `$.mobile.navigate("#bar", {transition: "slide", info: "info about the #bar hash"});`
2. `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "target", {transition: "flow", changeHash: false, reload: true})`

Just thought I'd answer this question from what I've learnt from the other threads.
I don't have enough reputation to put up the rest of the links. Just search the code up on Google to find their respective StackOverflow threads.

Comment: A bit late, but I will have a look into it, when I need it again